# String variable acting strange when writing to text file

Tags: string, powershell, character-encoding, newline, powershell-4.0

Below is the code I am having trouble with. It pulls from a `config.txt` file and sets information to `childofRoot.properties` file. for some reason the string when I set it is coming with extra added on.

```bsh
$date = (Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy'_'HH-mm")
$backup = 'backuplocation'
$temp = 'replace'
$p = ($PSScriptRoot + 'childofRoot.properties')


$cuidConf = Get-Content -Path ($PSScriptRoot + 'config.txt') | Select-String "cuids_rootfolder=" | Out-String
$cuidConf = $cuidConf.replace("cuids_rootfolder=", "").replace("`n", "")
$cuids = $cuidConf.Split(";")

$backuppath = ((Get-Content -Path ($PSScriptRoot + 'config.txt'))) | Select-String "backuplocation=" | Out-String
$backuppath = $backuppath.replace("backuplocation=", "").replace("`n", "")
$backuppath = $backuppath + $date + "\"


$foldername, $cuid = ($cuids[0].Split(","))

$backup1 = ($backuppath + "Folder a.lcmbiar")
        


((Get-content -Path $p).replace($temp, $cuid)) | Set-Content -Path $p

((Get-content -Path $p).replace($backup, $backup1)) | Set-Content -Path $p
```

Contents of `config.txt`:

```
backuplocation=C:\backuplcm\backupfiles\
```

Content of `childofRoot.properties`:

```
exportLocation=backuplocation
```

Expected output written to `childofRoot.properties`:

```
exportLocation=C:\backuplcm\backupfiles\08-18-2020_17-59\Folder\a.lcmbiar
```

Output I'm seeing written to `childofRoot.properties`:

```
exportLocation=
C:\backuplcm\backupfiles\


08-18-2020_18-02\Folder a.lcmbiar
```

Yes I already tried removing new line characters with `` .replace("`n","") ``
I had others look at this script too and the variable looks fine just when i set it it comes out different in the text file.
I was able to replicate this on Powershell 4 and Powershell 5 on different machines. If someone would try this on their machine and see if they can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra line breaks are from doing `| Select-String "backuplocation=" | Out-String`, and the reason `` .Replace("`n", "") `` doesn't solve the problem is that Windows uses the sequence `` "`r`n" `` for line breaks.

I suggest simplifying your script with `Where-Object` instead of `Select-String | Out-String`:

```bsh
$backuppath = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot config.txt) | Where-Object {$_ -match "backuplocation="}
$backuppath = $backuppath -replace 'backuplocation='
```